# OkHttp ResponseBody.string() выкидывает SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Мой ответ от сервера выглядит так:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal server error
Date: Mon, 24 Oct 2022 10:37:05 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Content-а соответственно нет.
Вызывая в Interceptor-е метод `chain.proceed(chain.request()).body()!!.string()`, вылетает SocketTimeoutException спустя некоторое время ожидания (при этом ожидаемое поведение - метод вернет пустую строку):

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
W/System.err:     at okio.SocketAsyncTimeout.newTimeoutException(JvmOkio.kt:146)
W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout.access$newTimeoutException(AsyncTimeout.kt:158)
W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:337)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.kt:189)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$AbstractSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:389)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$UnknownLengthSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:529)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.java:286)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.kt:189)
W/System.err:     at com.chuckerteam.chucker.internal.support.TeeSource.read(TeeSource.kt:24)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.select(RealBufferedSource.kt:229)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:467)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:181)
W/System.err:     at ServerErrorConverter.getResponseContent(ServerErrorConverter.kt:156)
```

Никак не могу понять, в чем причина. Удалось только установить, что если передавать также хедер `Content-Length: 0`, то такой проблемы не возникает.

Comment: Как по мне, так все логично. keep-alive держит соединение, Content-Length отсутствует, соответственно клиент ничего не знает о body и ждет его, пока не отвалится по таймауту. Либо рвите соединение, либо передавайте Content-Length.

Comment: Если я правильно помню - тело да, в таком случае будет пустое. Надо проверять, что код ответа не 200 и вызывать не `body`, но `errorBody`